# how do i execute a command after grep from a find in linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to delete every file that I find using find , But I also have to use grep to fine tune the search. Executing after find works

```
sudo find -name file-name  -exec rm -R {} \;
```

I have tried to delete after grep and it does not work

```
sudo find -name file-name | grep keyword -exec rm -R {} \;
```

how do i -exec after grep

Comment: What is it you want to achieve with that? Do you want to delete files that contain a keyword, files whose name contains a keyword, or are the files you find lists of filenames from which you want to extract the names of files to delete?

Comment: Is it just me that finds `sudo find <something> -exec rm -R {} \;` very dangerous? Especially playing around with it?

Comment: lol it is dangerous, but if you ain't living on the edge you are taking up too much space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo find . -name file-name -exec grep keyword '{}' \;-print | xargs  rm -R
```

Comment: what does '{}' do and how does xargs know what to rm

Comment: '{}' is the list of output of find. -name filename and grep will execute on top of it. Input of xrags are coming from the pipe(|)  so  it knows what should be deleted

Comment: This is going to send the output of grep into xargs rm -R,  that's not what the OP wants.